# How to detect a swipe without detecting a tap in kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, imageview, gesturedetector, ontouch

I have been programming an app in kotlin. This app allows a user to swipe through an **imageView** and plays a sound when a user taps the screen. The **onSwipeTouchListener** class below is the **onTouchListener** for my imageView. I am using the **onSwipeTouchListener** to also listen for taps so that the app can play a sound when the user taps the screen.  The issue is when a user swipes, the program detects a tap as well as a swipe. This results in the app playing a sound when it is not supposed to.

If someone could help me with this bug I'd much appreciate it.

here is my code:

```
package com.example.articulate_r

import android.animation.Animator
import android.content.Context
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.net.Uri
import android.view.GestureDetector
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView

open class OnSwipeTouchListener(
    private val ctx: Context,
    private val imageView: ImageView,
    private val textView: TextView,
    private val firstAnimatorRight: Animator,
    private val secondAnimatorRight: Animator,
    private val firstAnimatorLeft: Animator,
    private val secondAnimatorLeft: Animator
) : View.OnTouchListener {
    private val gestureDetector: GestureDetector

    companion object {
        private val SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100
        private val SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100
    }

    init {
        gestureDetector = GestureDetector(ctx, GestureListener())
    }

    override fun onTouch(v: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

    private inner class GestureListener : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        lateinit private var audioPlayer1 : MediaPlayer
        override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            playAudio(audioFiles[counter])
            return true
        }

        override fun onFling(
            e1: MotionEvent,
            e2: MotionEvent,
            velocityX: Float,
            velocityY: Float
        ): Boolean {

            var result = false
            try {
                val diffX = e2.x - e1.x
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight()
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft()
                        }
                        result = true
                    }

            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace()
            }

            return result
        }


    }
    var images = arrayOf(R.drawable.minecow, R.drawable.minepig,R.drawable.minechick)
    var imageNames = arrayOf("Cows", "Pigs", "Chickens")
    var audioFiles = arrayOf(R.raw.cows_and, R.raw.pigs_and, R.raw.chickens_and)
    var counter = 0
    open fun onSwipeRight() {
        println("swiped right")
        if (counter == 0) {
            counter = images.size - 1
        }
        else {
            counter--
        }
        animateRight(images[counter])
        textView.text = imageNames[counter]
        println(counter)
    }

    open fun onSwipeLeft() {
        println("swiped left")
        if (counter == images.size - 1) {
            counter = 0
        }
        else {
            counter++
        }
        animateLeft(images[counter])
        textView.text = imageNames[counter]
        println(counter)
    }

     private fun playAudio(audioFile: Int) {
         var audioPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, audioFile)
         audioPlayer.setVolume(100f,100f)
         audioPlayer.start()
    }

    private fun animateLeft(drawableImage: Int) {
        firstAnimatorLeft.setTarget(imageView)
        secondAnimatorLeft.setTarget(imageView)

        firstAnimatorLeft.setDuration(250)
        secondAnimatorLeft.setDuration(250)
        firstAnimatorLeft.start()

        firstAnimatorLeft.addListener(
            object : Animator.AnimatorListener {

                override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator) {

                }

                override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(ctx.getDrawable(drawableImage))
                    secondAnimatorLeft.start()
                }

                override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator) {}
                override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animator?) {}

            }
        )
    }

    private fun animateRight(drawableImage: Int) {
        firstAnimatorRight.setTarget(imageView)
        secondAnimatorRight.setTarget(imageView)

        firstAnimatorRight.setDuration(250)
        secondAnimatorRight.setDuration(250)
        firstAnimatorRight.start()

        firstAnimatorRight.addListener(
            object : Animator.AnimatorListener {

                override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator) {

                }

                override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(ctx.getDrawable(drawableImage))
                    secondAnimatorRight.start()
                }

                override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator) {}
                override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animator?) {}

            }
        )
    }

}
```